# referencing a variable as directive template content

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to set a string-variable as the content of a template?
I'd like to select two different templates depending on the scope.
Something like this:

```
define(['app'], function(app){
    app.directive('logstorelist', function(){
        var temp="";
        return{
            scope: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(s, e, a){
                if(a=="a")
                    temp = "<a>tempA</a>";
                else
                    temp = "<div>temp</div>";
            },
            replace: true,
            template: temp
        }
    })
});
```

Is anything like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use only one template and use `ng-switch` to load content depending on your scope variable (if you don't mind the extra `<span>`):

```
define(['app'], function(app){
    app.directive('logstorelist', function(){
        var temp="";
        return{
            scope: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(s, e, a){
                s.temp = a;
            },
            replace: true,
            template: 
            ' <span ng-switch="temp">
                <a ng-switch-when="a">tempA</a>
                <div ng-switch-default>temp</div>
            </span>'
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thx, that worked out very well :)
There are a lot of function I still have to get aware of.

Comment: Oh, I should say that it's not ng-switch on="temp". It's to be ng-switch="temp" ...